# Product of commutator subgroup of a nilpotent group with another subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to solve the following statement which was given to me as an excersice.

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group and $H \le G$ so that $G=HG'$. Show that $G=H$

I tried to use induction on nilpotency class and I also tried showing that $H$ equals it's normalizer but I'm kind of stuck.

Can you give me any hints?

Comment: Let $G=\gamma_1(G) \ge \gamma_2(G) \ge \cdots \ge 1$ be the lower central series of $G$. Then $G=H\gamma_2(G) \Rightarrow \gamma_2(G) = \gamma_2(H)\gamma_3(G) \Rightarrow G = H \gamma_3(G)$. Prove similarly that $G=H\gamma_i(G)$ for $i=3,4,5,\ldots$.